# Regex to find arguments in text

Tags: regex, vb.net

There's undoubtedly a better way to do this but this is the way my requirements need me to do this.

I'm creating a search form for my web application. I want to use a tagged based search. So I'm using regex to make it work.

So I have a search string: 'c:john customer:15478'
The regex needs to find the tag (c:) and the argument (john), drop the tag, and give me the argument -- and it needs to do so for all of the instances of a tag and their arguments. The regex I have comes close, but it doesn't work correctly. It doesn't grab every argument, or drop the tags in a consistent way. So the question: what's wrong with my regex that needs to be fixed in order to achieve the correct results?

Currently it finds the first tag, grabs its argument, and everything else after it. I need it to stop the match after it finds an argument. i.e. in the case above it will match john customer:15478

Maybe a better question is how do I make VB's regex return everything between the first colon, and the beginning of the next tag (which is followed by another colon) or otherwise stop matching at the beginning of the next tag?

Regex:

```
(?<=({0}({1})??:)+?)(\S+\s*\S*)(?=\s+?\b\w+:.+?)??
```

The `{0}` and the `{1}` represent a String.format call using a string, say Customer (but it could be anything), to define the tag. the `{0}` is the first character, and the `{1}` are the rest of the characters. This regex will match anything that exists behind the tag including another tag and its argument if it exists. So for the string

```
"c:5401 4664  c:john smith p:joam d:domain.com p:1548 c:215-548-5487 d:""192.168.0.1"""
```

The matches would be

```
'5401 4664, john smith, 215-548-5487 d:"192.168.0.1"'
'domain.com p:1548, "192.168.0.1"'
'joam d:domain.com, 1548 c:215-548-5487'
```

given the tags I have defined. The regex fails to stop its matching at the start of the next tag.

Comment: Have you tried: http://www.regexr.com/ ?

Comment: yes, and it's javascript based. This is for a VB application.

Answer (score 1):

If I undestood You correctly this should solve the problem in general:

```
/\w+:([^:]+)(?:\s|$)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/vN6fH1/1

and with defined tag it would look like this:

```
/{0}({1})?:([^:]+)(?:\s|$)/g
```

but this still rely on semicolon not tag name

(so it won't match at all if You did not pass tag name that is in string)

Comment: That seems to work beautifully. It's also simple, short, and to the point. I'll have to test in in vb but it should work. I'll mark this as the answer if it works.